# Issue in ReactJS using Fetch creating a form and calling back a ID with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, fetch

Good day I was hoping someone could help me I am having a issue with this form I am creating basically I need the returned ID and processes the new contact with the ID that same here is a snippet of my code I can not figure what is the correct syntax to return the id

```
fetch('api/contact', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstname: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
    lastname: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    subject: document.getElementById("subject").value,
    message: document.getElementById("message").value
})
  .then(function(response) {
    return fetch('api/admin/process', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "action": "NewContact",
        "data": { id: response.data // I AM HAVING THE ISSUE HERE}
```

I was wondering if anyone had a idea on a fix, Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `data` of `response.data` the whole data object that you expect? Or is it a field of the whole object? My answer, below, assumed the former, but then I realized that it might need to be corrected, slightly, if you meant the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the fetch response is not the data itself, but an object from which the data can be retrieved. Assuming that a valid JSON response awaits, the response object has a method that returns a JSON object, `response.json()`. That method, however, returns a promise, as well.

```
.then( function (response) {
    return response.json()
})
.then( function (json) {
   fetch('api/admin/process', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
     body: JSON.stringify({
      "action": "NewContact",
      "data": { id: json.data 
…
```

Comment: Basically in order for me to access the id that is created in the api/contact I use response.data syntax if I put a contact in the id area that is already created for example id:"61" the form successfully works I am have issues pulling in the id of the contact that is created once the user presses the submit button so far I have used response.data and response.data.id each one of these objects is giving me a 500 error code or responseData = undefined

Comment: The important thing to notice, as I show in my example, the actual content from the first `fetch` is _not_ part of the response parameter passed to the `.then` function. Instead, it must be “extracted” via a call to the parameter’s `text()` or `json()` methods (depending on what form you want the content). In your code, you were accessing `response.data`, which does not exist.

Comment: If I understood you, @JayThelastcipherDaniels, your expected response from the first `fetch` is something like `{ "data": "61"}` ? Then the adjustment I just made to the example should work—I added the `data` property to the `json` object passed to the `id` field of the next `fetch` call.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance I actually fixed the problem is was a problem with how I wrote the syntax the request was being passed through the res I had to rewrite the code here is the answer if anyone else has the same problem

```
handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
fetch('api/contact', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
body: JSON.stringify({
firstname: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
      lastname: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
      email: document.getElementById("email").value,
      subject: document.getElementById("subject").value,
      message: document.getElementById("message").value
}),    
})

.then((response) => { return response.json()} )
.then((res) => { 
  console.log('res')
  return fetch('api/admin/process', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({"action": "NewContact", "data" : 
    { 
      id: res.id } 

  }),

  })
})
```